# Login Form validation in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to put a *ngIf directive after the login button that will catch the errors made by the signin function. Is there any way to display the error message with this?

Below is my logincomponent.ts

```
constructor(private router: Router,
private loginService: LoginService,
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private fb: FormBuilder){}    

ngOnInit() {
this.form = this.fb.group({
username: [''],
password: ['']
});


signin(form) {
Auth.signIn(form.username, form.password).then(user => {
localStorage.setItem('access_token', user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken);
this.getUserInfo();
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Below is my login.component.html file

```
<div *ngIf="!adSignin">
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="signin(form.value)">
        <h6 class="primary">Login</h6>
        <div>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
            <input matInput placeholder="User" formControlName="username" 
            autocomplete="univers-user" id="username">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
            <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" 
            formControlName="password" autocomplete="univers-password" id="password">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need catch the error inside your service/component and save error or just error message to variable and then use it to display inside div bellow the login button.

And do not forget to set some boolean flag to true when you will have error while login.

```html
 <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    .....
    
    <div *ngIf="errorWhileLogin">
      <p>
        Some error while login:
        {{this.err.message}}
      </p>
    </div>
```

set it inside you service method like this:

```js
this.getUserInfo();
}).catch(err => {

console.log(err)
this.errorWhileLogin = true;
this.error = err;
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
error: string;

constructor(private router: Router,
  private loginService: LoginService,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private fb: FormBuilder
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    username: [''],
    password: ['']
  });
}

async signin(form) {
  try {
    const user = await Auth.signIn(form.username, form.password);
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken);
    this.getUserInfo();
  } catch (err) {
    this.error = err;
  }
}
```

Then in template:

```
<div *ngIf="!adSignin">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="signin(form.value)">
    <h6 class="primary">Login</h6>
    <div>
      <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
        <input matInput placeholder="User" formControlName="username" autocomplete="univers-user" id="username">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
      <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
        <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" autocomplete="univers-password" id="password">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="error">
      {{ error }}
    </div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
```